# Show that $X^3+X^2+1$ has only one real root

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Consider the polynomial $X^3+X^2+1 \in \mathbb R [X]$. Since it is of odd degree, it has at least one real root. How can I show that it's the only one?

Comment: Root is when there is an equation . Here it would be zeroes as we assume the polynomial is equal to zero. Try to write the polynomial as a G.P

Comment: I disagree. The statement of the fundamental theorem of algebra is that every nonconstant polynomial with complex coefficients has a complex root - there is no mention of an equation.

Comment: Hint: study the derivative of $x\mapsto  x^3+x^2+1$ and thus the behaviour of your function.

Comment: Use [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not quite a duplicate - that question was about $x^3+x+c$

Comment: @almagest And the answer there of Mark Bennet is about *all* cubic polynomials with exactly one real root :)

Comment: @Showhat Indeed, I'd say that polynomials have roots, functions have zeroes, and equations have solutions

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I didn't say it wasn't. My comment makes my objection perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two possible approaches:

1. Let $f(x)=x^3+x^2+1$. Differentiate $f$ to find the maxima and minima; $f$ will have three real roots iff the local maximum is above the $x$-axis and the local minimum is below the axis.
2. If you want an algebraic proof, suppose for the sake of contradiction that the polynomial has real roots $a,b,c$. Then $abc=-1$ by Vieta's formulas, so at least one of $a,b,c$ has absolute value at least 1. But 
   $$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=1,$$ again by Vieta's, and this is a contradiction since none of $a,b,c$ is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no positive root as all terms are positive. Zero is not a root. To check for negative roots, consider $-x^3+x^2+1$, which has only one sign change, so by [Descartes rule of signs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Negative_roots), the polynomial has exactly one negative root.

Answer (score 2):

Derivative being equal to $0$
$$3x^2+2x=0$$
gives $x_1=0$ and $x_2=\frac{-2}{3}$ and in our initial polynomial we have
$p(0)=1$ and $p(\frac{-2}{3})>0$ hence it never crosses the $0$ line again and cannot have any additional zeros amongst the real